# Problem when downloading a file

Tags: android

Here's the problem I'm facing : I try to download a file from a tomcat server using the following snipet of code

```
try
 {
   BufferedInputStream getit = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("http://192.168.2.180:8080/android.apk").openStream());
   FileOutputStream saveit = new FileOutputStream(path);
   BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(saveit,1024);
   byte data[] = new byte[1024];
   int readed = getit.read(data,0,1024);
   while(readed != -1)
    {
        bout.write(data,0,readed);
        readed = getit.read(data,0,1024);
    }
    bout.close();
    getit.close();
    saveit.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace
}
```

The above works just fine when I run it on the emulator , but when I try to test it on my device it doesn't do anything  , and ~50 sec later it throws a "socket timeout"exception at the line

```
 BufferedInputStream getit = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("http://192.168.2.180:8080/android.apk").openStream());
```

What is this happening and how can I fix it ?

here's the stacktrace

```
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectSocketImpl(Native Method)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(OSNetworkSystem.java:125)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:227)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:521)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1019)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:67)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:151)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:73)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:826)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:812)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1054)
04-19 12:28:19.865: WARN/System.err(2962): at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:674)
```

Comment: is the host IP: http://192.168.2.180:8080/ available on public network?

Comment: this my comp IP !  Frankly I don't know , how can I check this ?

Comment: Yes it is. From another comp on the same network I typed 192.168.2.180:8080 in a browser , and the tomcat home page was loaded

Comment: @klaus-vlad: you device is using 3g or wifi? What ip does the device have?

Comment: wifi , I don't know  yet what IP does the device have.

Comment: Settings => Wireless & networks => Wi-Fi settings => (Click on the one you are connected to).

Comment: The ip is: 172.16.42.119

Comment: Try doing a ping from 192.168.2.180 to 172.16.42.119.

Comment: I tried :Destination port unreachable for all 4 packets

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the port 8080, try with a default url like http://www.google.com.
(default port = 80) It will work.

Answer (score 0):

As Samuh said, check that you have access to the private ip.
Also you should catch that timeout exception correctly, showing a dialog to the user or a Toast.

Remember that if you are willing to use 3g in your phone for you application, I would recommend increasing the timeout values using something like:

```
setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
```